# responsive images on entire page

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I would like to ensure that all images on a page are responsive is there a way this can be done. I have a responsive CMS, the users are able to update images via tinyMCE and File Manager but I don't trust them to get the image sizes correct.

Comment: So what do you mean by responsive

Comment: You mean auto size the `img` before displaying (`I don't trust them to get the image sizes correct`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common relative solution is to set the max-width of the image at 100% and set height to auto.

please check this link:

http://demosthenes.info/blog/586/CSS-Fluid-Image-Techniques-for-Responsive-Site-Design